# Prevent the parent node from being affected by child physics body in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm a long time web developer but this is the first time I have made a game or worked with Objective C. I really (really!) like working with Objective C so far and have gotten quite far on my game. Thanks in advance for your help!

I'm trying to make 3 spike balls that are SKSpriteNodes rotate in a circle around my hero ship (see image) after the hero gets a pickup. All looks and animates great until I add physics bodies to the balls, which are required so they can collide with monsters. I want the hero ship to be unaffected by the attached physics bodies so that the hero movement can remain smooth and constant – I'm moving the hero with:

```
    [self.heroShip.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(moveByX, moveByY)];.
```

[image]

Here it is without the physics bodies. I'm attaching 3 children nodes to an anchor node, attaching the anchor node to the hero ship, and then rotating the anchor. The following animation looks exactly like I want it to.

```
    SKSpriteNode * spikeballAnchor = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] init];

    SKSpriteNode * spikeball1   = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"spikeball"];
    spikeball1.name             = HERO_SPIKEBALL;
    spikeball1.position         = CGPointMake(100, 0);
    [spikeballAnchor addChild:spikeball1];

    SKSpriteNode * spikeball2   = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"spikeball"];
    spikeball2.name             = HERO_SPIKEBALL;
    spikeball2.position         = CGPointMake(-50, 86);
    [spikeballAnchor addChild:spikeball2];

    SKSpriteNode * spikeball3   = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"spikeball"];
    spikeball3.name             = HERO_SPIKEBALL;
    spikeball3.position         = CGPointMake(-50, -86);
    [spikeballAnchor addChild:spikeball3];

    [spikeballAnchor runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction rotateByAngle:(M_PI_2 * 2) duration:1]]];

    [self.heroShip addChild:spikeballAnchor];
```

But the spike balls need to collide with enemy monsters! When I add the following physics body to a spike ball it quickly flies out of orbit.

```
    SKSpriteNode * spikeball1   = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"spikeball"];
    spikeball1.name             = HERO_SPIKEBALL;
    spikeball1.position         = CGPointMake(100, 0);
    spikeball1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:spikeball1.size];
    spikeball1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = spikeballCategory;
    spikeball1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = monsterCategory;
    spikeball1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask   = defaultCategory;
    [spikeballAnchor addChild:spikeball1];
```

Ok. So I have tried just about everything I can think of and have scoured the web for a solution. Giving examples of everything I have tried would take a lot of space so I'll summarize.

I have tried making the anchor a physics body, pinning the spike balls to the anchor, and pinning the anchor to the hero. No luck.

I have tried creating a SKPhysicsJointLimit, SKPhysicsJointPin, and a SKPhysicsJointFixed between the anchor and the balls. In all the these rigs the physics of the spike balls throw the ship off. I have tried setting the mass of the anchor and the balls to zero. Strangely, even with no mass, they still seem to affect the ship's movement. Additionally I have tried setting friction, linearDamping, and angularDamping of the physics bodies to zero.

Also the joints only seem to work when I add the child nodes before setting the physics bodies.

The following is the closest/best result I have gotten (one spike ball in example) but I am unable to make the rotation of the balls not affect the ship! When I run this the ball does not rotate consistently (the ship's movement speeds up and slows down the rotation around the joint) and the movement of the ball throws the ship's movement off, creating an undesirable pendulum effect on the ship. This needs to work with 2 and 1 ball as they get destroyed.

```
    SKSpriteNode * spikeballAnchor = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
    [self.heroShip addChild:spikeballAnchor];
    spikeballAnchor.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:spikeballAnchor.size];
    spikeballAnchor.physicsBody.pinned = true;
    spikeballAnchor.name = HERO_SPIKEBALL;

    SKSpriteNode * spikeball1   = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"spikeball"];
    spikeball1.name             = HERO_SPIKEBALL;
    spikeball1.position         = CGPointMake(100, 0);
    [spikeballAnchor addChild:spikeball1];
    spikeball1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:spikeball1.size];
    spikeball1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = spikeballCategory;
    spikeball1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = monsterCategory;
    spikeball1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask   = defaultCategory;

    [spikeballAnchor runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction rotateByAngle:(M_PI_2 * 2) duration:1]]];

    SKPhysicsJointFixed * joint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:spikeballAnchor.physicsBody bodyB:spikeball1.physicsBody anchor:spikeballAnchor.position];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
```

I have considered trying to move the anchor and its children independently of the ship but I'm worried they will get out of sync and it will add a little more management to remove them when the hero dies if the anchor is not a child of the hero. But that's not a deal breaker if I can keep their position's perfectly in sync.

Sorry for being so verbose. Any help is most appreciated!

```
// Collision Bits

static const int defaultCategory            = 0;
static const int projectileCategory         = 1;
static const int spikeballCategory          = 2;
static const int monsterCategory            = 3;
static const int heroCategory               = 4;
static const int pickupCategory             = 5;
static const int boundariesCategory         = 50;
```

Comment: Since you want the Spike Balls' physics bodies to detect contacts, but not collisions, you need to set the collisionBitMask to 0. Also, how have you declared your category bitmask values?

Comment: Yep. I have my "defaultCategory" constant set to 0. I'll add my bitMasks to the post. I think I have found a working solution. Setting mass to `spikeball1.physicsBody.mass = 0.000001f;` makes the effect on the ship completely un-noticeable. Can someone explain to me why setting Mass to Zero stops the parent hero ship's movement completely?  `spikeball1.physicsBody.mass = 0.000000f;`

Comment: For the record someone deleted their response that suggested I do in fact try to move the spike ball anchor independently of the hero ship and keep their positions in sync with: `- (void) didSimulatePhysics
{
    self.spikeballAnchor.position = self.heroShip.position;
}`. I haven't tried this yet but it seems like another good solution. They suggested I attach both the hero ship and the anchor to a separate SKNode layer so I can remove them simultaneously on destruction of the ship. Thanks to the user who posted that!

Comment: It's better to post working solution as an answer and accept it. You can answer your own question too.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to a question so a bit offtopic, but I see another problem in your code: your categories are intersecting, because they are used as bitmasks. I mean, your `monsterCategory` includes `spikeballCategory` and `projectileCategory`, because in binary `3 = 1 | 2`.

```
  monsterCategory      3   0b00000011  
  projectileCategory   1   0b00000001  
  spikeballCategory    2   0b00000010
```

So you might notice your spikeballs can act like monsters and vice versa, and projectiles can act like monsters and vice versa.

Comment: Yes I have seen this in examples. I need to fix it. This project is on hold while I get some other stuff done. I will look at this when I pick it back up. Thanks!